# Query Builder appending a limit by itself

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a "big" query with 10 joins, and finally a single where condition.

I also have about 6 arrays, each being filled with a select statement from said query.

```php
$first_array = $query->select()->first();
```

In two of the arrays, I get the data using `get()` instead of `first()`. The issue is, the `get()` method is only returning one row, when I know for a fact that there are two that match the condition. I used the `toSql()` method to see the resulting query, only to find there is a `limit 1` being appended to the query that I did not place. Is the limit being appended because I'm using `first()` in some of the queries, which is limiting my results to one row? I've tried executing the query in my database manager and after removing the `limit 1` from the query it does return the two rows I'm expecting.

Comment: Bit of a hack, but can you try explicitly adding ->limit(PHP_INT_MAX)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand, you want me to enforce a limit that is higher than the 1 being appended?

Comment: I tried assigning a limit of 5, it's still executing as 1.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was, if you did this like I did:

```php
$array1 = $query->select()->first();
$array2 = $query->select()->first();
$array3 = $query->select()->first();
$array4 = $query->select()->first();
$array5 = $query->select()->get();
```

The `first()` method calls set the `limit 1`, and using `get()` afterwards does not remove the limit.

If you use `get()` first then `first()` like so:

```php
$array5 = $query->select()->get();
$array1 = $query->select()->first();
$array2 = $query->select()->first();
$array3 = $query->select()->first();
$array4 = $query->select()->first();
```

then the issue does not occur.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `first()` with `get()` is the answer. `first()` is for retrieving a single model: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#retrieving-single-models where `get()` returns you the collection of results: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#collections